# Integrate a D3.js tree into a angular 4 project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, tree

I'm working on a webpage and I want to visualize a certain tree structure.
I bumped into this beautiful D3.js tree (http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033), but I'm having trouble importing it into my project since there are several ways (dg3-ng2 for example).

D3.js is a javascript-libary - and Angular works with typescript.

How do I integrate that certain tree into my project so that I also can modify it without any trouble afterwards?
I do have several questions like:

- Where do I import the .js and the .json file?
- Do I have to convert the javascript code into typescript manually?
- Should I write the .js code into a .ts file?
- Should I make a  reference in my index.html?
- Should I make use of a D3-Service?

As you can see I'm quiet confused.

Comment: Any luck on it developing? If so can please share it in code spinet

Answer (score 0):

If you use Angular, it's simple)

1. Istall d3 from npm.
2. Import d3 in component like that:

   ```
   import * as d3 from 'd3';
   ```
3. And write you logic, use d3 syntaxis, example:

   `constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
           this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
           this.host = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);
   }`

You graphic is a component, in you component descrite functions to build svg, draw axis and etc.
Then on init of component call  methods that you describe, example:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setup();
        this.buildSVG();
        this.drawFirstPlanRects();
        this.drawSecondPlanRects();
        this.drawXAxis();
        this.drawYAxis();
        this.drawCrossLines();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. But I still have no idea. Do you mind answering my questions?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd strongly recommend using angular-cli since when you install the d3 library you won't have to deal with the boiler plate of hooking it into the app properly. You'd just need to import it into your ts document like the above example shows. On importing the json there are several different ways that it could be handled. You could just store the json in a variable in the .ts file, you could store it in a static json document that you then host along with the app and there a many examples of pulling files and loading json data out there already.
2. You don't have to convert any of the js code you have since ts is essentially js with types, though you might have to declare an any type for some things, but if you want ts code you will have to manually convert or find a ts example. I'd strongly recommend a good IDE that is compatible with ts. It'll do a lot of the heavy lifting of finding mistakes.
3. It's rather difficult to answer that question since I don't know the specs of your project. Generally if you are doing a one off thing that does't need angular I'd just keep it simple with js and drop the usage of angular. If this is part of a larger app though I'd recommend writing it in ts since angular2+ is written in ts and most examples you find online will be in ts.
4. If you are using angular-cli you won't need to make a reference in your index.html file
5. I'm not sure what you are asking here.

From the questions you are asking I'd strongly recommend really looking at angular and learning how to properly create an app with it and then figure out how to integrate d3 int the project, since some of the questions you are asking aren't related to just working with d3 in angular.